# How code analysis part of ChatGPT works and trained

Tags: neural-networks, transformer, chatgpt

ChatGPT can explain given code snippet we also ask question like "What does this variable do" , "Why this is used" and all. I gave C++ function snippet from an popular Open Source project it was able explain complete context how this function can be used and it is used in project even though snippet I gave only contained that particular function. This has baffled me. I understand that they might have fed all Open Source project codebases to it.

But what I wonder how might they have trained it. Like given the code how to make Neural networks do analysis on it and make it answer the query? I'm really curious to learn it.

I know OpenAI did not really publish proper research paper on this. But still anyone can tell me or guide me how **might** they have done it.

Comment: It is just a Large Language Model. Very large. Terabytes. You can run GPT-2 at home and it is basically doing the same thing, only worse.